# Update pushed git commits

Tags: git, github

I need a simple solution to update the commits i made in a pull request.

I frequently make small corrections on my code and i dont want the git history of that branch to look completely messy for the others, so i need a way to combine multiple small updates into one single commit.

I already tried squashing with `git rebase -i`, but it never worked, the single updates still remained.

Can anyone provide me with step by step instructions for the commandline or sourcetree GUI?

Comment: How is `git rebase -i` not working?

Comment: After i make the rebase, i still have each single commit individually present in the history. :(

Comment: That's strange, did you tried the `fixup` option of `git rebase -i`?

Answer (score 0):

You should first do:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~{number of commits back your want to review}
```

Then you should remove `pick` and type `s` or `f` depending on whether you want to modify the message or not.

When you have finished that, if it fails you should resolve your conflicts and do `git rebase --continue`. If there were no conflicts then you're good to go. If you want to have a clean history on the remote you should do:

```
git push --force
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT -** If you really need to remove pushed commits, you can do that with the command `git revert SHA1`. This will create a *cancel* commit, where all the lines you added are removed and vice-versa.

If you have 2 commits to remove, you need to cancel them in reverse order (older first) :

```
git revert SHA1-of-commit-2
git revert SHA1-of-commit-1
git push
```

### Local commits

You did the right command, which is `git rebase -i HEAD~2` to rewrite 2 commits (change the number 2 accordingly). Then the following screen will appear. You need to use `squash` to remove the commit but keep the content.

Here the BUG-2 will merge into BUG-1 and you'll have a nice history to push (just `git push` that after you are finished).

```
pick 4ef60e2 BUG-1
squash 1d07893 BUG-2

# Rebase 10ff948..00e24be onto 10ff948
#
# Commands:
#  ...
```

### Pushed commits

Pushed commit are permanent, unless you are working alone and willing to "rewrite history", which consists of rewinding the remote branch. To suppress one commit, you do `git reset --hard HEAD~1` (change the number 1 accordingly) and then force the rewrite with `git push -f`. **Use with caution and only if you know what you are doing**.

Comment: Yes, i would like to squash commits that are already pushed.
My collaborators asked my specifically to do so.

So, if i type it "reset --hard HEAD~1" followed by "git push -f" - doesnt that mean that the changes made to the lates commit are thrown away?

Comment: Yes, if you are working with collaborators, do not force push, that might erase late commits. The only way to remove your pushed commits is to cancel them with the command `git revert`. I'll update my answer.